# How to Create a Copy of an Envelope in DocuSign using rest api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Is there a REST API method to create a copy of an envelope? This option is available for all the envelopes(any status) in the DocuSign manage section. Is there an API method to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

After lots of searching and trying i have finally found the solution. Now i am posting my ans so that it can help anyone.

For 'Create a Copy' First you need to create an envelope then in its EnvelopeDefinition just mention two things that is "Status" set as sent or created as per your requirement and "Envelopeid" this include the envelope ID you're trying to copy as the value. And you are good to go.

My Code ......

```
public string CreateCopyEnvelopeAndSendEmail(string EnvelopeID, string url)  
{
   var docuSignClient = new DocuSignClient(this.DocuSignCredentials);
   var accountId = docuSignClient.AccountId;
   EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();           

    var options = new ReturnUrlRequest();
    options.ReturnUrl = url;

    var envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition()
        {               
            Status = "created",
            EnvelopeId = EnvelopeID
        };   

    EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
   // create the sender view
   ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.CreateSenderView(accountId,
         envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, options);
   return recipientView.Url.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for supplying the answer!